# legit emails in junkbox

Tags: email, spam

Hey this is actually a reverse question.
My personal email (firstname.lasname@gmail.com) is winding up in many peoples junkbox and I have no idea why.

What may the cause be? Is it because it has the word Entrepreneur (and programmer) in my sig? is it because my first name is unique(european like)?

Its driving me crazy. I sent out dozens of business emails a month to people I just meet so its actually hurting me much more then others :(

-edit-

I also want to mention this is non spam. Typically I email people I meet and say hi or to follow up. I was requested by someone to send him an email so I can test something, so I did and he replied to me 10 days later telling me he found it in his junk, like many others have said to me.

-edit-

bortzmeyer suggested emailing check-auth@verifier.port25.com I did and here are the results

```
SPF check:          pass
DomainKeys check:   pass
DKIM check:         pass
Sender-ID check:    pass
SpamAssassin check: ham

----------------------------------------------------------
SpamAssassin check details:
----------------------------------------------------------
SpamAssassin v3.2.5 (2008-06-10)

Result:         ham  (-2.6 points, 5.0 required)

 pts rule name              description
---- ---------------------- --------------------------------------------------
-0.0 SPF_PASS               SPF: sender matches SPF record
-2.6 BAYES_00               BODY: Bayesian spam probability is 0 to 1%
                           [score: 0.0000]
 0.0 HTML_MESSAGE           BODY: HTML included in message
```

Answer (score 2):

Could one of your names be the name of a drug?  Think how Marlon Ribunal's name must cause spam triggers to go off since Ribunal is the name of a drug.  He and Johnny Viagra have the same problem.

Comment: haha, no. That was a good thought. Do you happen to know if it checks the sender name for drugs? because i could always remove my name from my sig

Comment: I am not sure if I'm amused by the mention of my name in the sample above. Anyway, I am giving this a +1 since the answer makes sense ;-)

Answer (score 2):

There can be many reasons for you being filtered out ("business emails" are very often full of spam indicators, such as content only in HTML, images, exclamation marks and sentences like "Buy now"). The reason is likely different at each recipient. If you want serious examination by ServerFault users and not random guesses (like most of the answers currently are), post an entire message here, complete with all its RFC 5322 headers.

And if you want an automatic test, send one of your message to `check-auth@verifier.port25.com`. It will automatically process your message, testing it with various anti-spam techniques and send you back a very detailed report with possible spamicity indicators. Here is an example:

```
==========================================================
Summary of Results
==========================================================
SPF check:          permerror
DomainKeys check:   neutral
DKIM check:         neutral
SpamAssassin check: ham
```

Then, if you don't understand everything in the report, post it here.

It seems that check-auth does not test if the sending IP address is in the typical black lists, that may be something to do (I use [rblcheck](http://rblcheck.wiki.sourceforge.net/)).

Comment: For SpamAssassin do i need to score above or below 5?
I posted my results above.

Comment: Not everyone uses SpamAssassin and, anyway, the score depends on the current set of rules, which is always changing. No, your report seems OK but, as I said, people can decide that your message is spam, based on many reasons, some plainly stupid (such as the presence of a PTR record in the DNS) and there is not much you can do.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider getting an email address at something other then gmail.  Some spam filters penalize you simply because you use a free email service.  Even a setting up your email free on googleapps using your own domain may be better then using gmail.com

There are lots of resources online that give advice about how to avoid spam filters, many these articles are targeted at lists, but at least some of that information can be applied to your personal account. information applies to maillist, but some of th

Here are a couple somewhat related questions from stackoverflow.

- [Avoid being blocked by web mail companies for mass/bulk emailing ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162149/avoid-being-blocked-by-web-mail-companies-for-mass-bulk-emailing)
- [How do you make sure email you send programmatically is not automatically marked as spam?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371/how-do-you-make-sure-email-you-send-programmatically-is-not-automatically-marked)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a URL in the body of the email?  A short email with a URL might trigger a spam filter.  I doubt if it has to do with firstname.lastname.  Perhaps the URL is perceived as spammy?  Perhaps the language makes it sound like you are selling something?  Are you using gmail's website to send because if you're sending from a non-gmail IP address, that would create a perception about it being spam.

Comment: No URLs but there is my email (the same email i am sending from) in my sig, would that cause it?

Comment: @acidzombie24 if the signature was edited in HTML, most of the time the email will be sifted out as spam. There are companies that specifically block "public emails". Public emails usually contains ads.

Answer (score 1):

For debugging purposes, you might want to have someone forward your "spammy" mail back to you (make sure to have them include all the headers). Many spam filters are configured to insert headers summarizing the results of various checks performed on the mail.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if gmail supports this or not, but my signature is actually a gif image of text.  Just a thought.

Comment: I would guess that that would increase, not decrease, how spammy the email seems.